# Prepared Statement not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute a prepared statement with mysqli but the statement never executes with results nor throws an error. But executing the query normally work.

The prepared query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE YEARweek(game_date)=?
```

The regular non prepared query is this

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE YEARweek(game_date)= YEARweek(current_DATE) +1
```

Any ideas why?

The code for executing the query is in different places but it looks like this in short version:

```
$WHERE_CLAUSE='';
        $first=true;
        if(isset($conditions['conditions'])) {
            foreach($conditions['conditions'] as $key=>$condition){
                    if(is_array($condition)){

                    } else {
                        if($first)
                            $WHERE_CLAUSE.=$key.'=?';
                        else 
                            $WHERE_CLAUSE.=' AND '.$key.'=?';

                        $input_data[$key]=$condition;
                        $first=false;
                    }
            }//end foreach

            if(!empty($WHERE_CLAUSE)){
                $query.='WHERE '.$WHERE_CLAUSE.' ';
            }
        }

        $result=PVDatabase::preparedSelect($query, $input_data);

public static function preparedQuery($query, $data, $formats = '') {

    if (self::_hasAdapter(get_class(), __FUNCTION__))
        return self::_callAdapter(get_class(), __FUNCTION__, $query, $data, $formats);

    if (self::$dbtype == self::$mySQLConnection) {
        self::$link -> prepare($query);
        $count = 1;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            self::$link -> bindParam($count, $value);
            $count++;
        }//end foreach

        return self::$link -> execute();
    } else if (self::$dbtype == self::$postgreSQLConnection) {
        $result = pg_prepare(self::$link, '', $query);
        $result = pg_execute(self::$link, '', $data);
        return $result;
    } else if (self::$dbtype == self::$oracleConnection) {

    } else if (self::$dbtype == self::$msSQLConnection) {
        $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare(self::$link, $query, $data);
        return sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    }

}//end preparedQuery
```

Comment: Have you bound any parameters to your statement? Perhaps it would be useful if you posted your code.

Comment: how do you call the function to execute the query?

Comment: What is the value of data you're passing into preparedQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't provided the code you're using to invoke the query, I'm going to guess that you are probably binding a value that includes an expression. Instead of being evaluated, it'll be interpreted literally.

Comment: Now, the code is there, but you still need to give us the value you're using to bind.

Answer (score 0):

PDO must be escaping the YEARweek(current_DATE) +1 part of the second query.

Do this instead:

```
$next_year = date('Y) + 1;

SELECT * FROM games WHERE YEARweek(game_date) = $next_year
```